# Auto-login after email validation and redirection to 'fos_user_profile_edit' path

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1

We're building a business app from the ground up in Symfony 3, and I've run into a bit of a snag with the user validation flow: after the user creates an account they will receive a validation email, then(after clicking the confirmation/validation link) they should be automatically authentificated and redirected to the edit profile.
But unfortunately they are redirected to the login page without any authentification.

Anyone had any experience with this, or able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of user bunle have you?

It is as folow, If email configuration has been set properly, when user are create ([registerAction](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php)), FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event are dispatch and [EmailConfirmationListener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailConfirmationListener.php) catch its and send email with the generated token.
This token is save in session and user have to be connected by using email confirmation with it related confirmation token [confirmAction](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php)

All depend on if admin email is set properly or not have a look there :
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#registration-confirmation

If email has not been set properly [addRegistrationSection](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) by default:

```
fos_user:
# ...
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: false
```

User should be connected directly

Comment: I'm not sure if this will authentifie automaticlly !!

Comment: in registration controller if event response has not been set in the listener, it would be set in your controller and then your user would be confirmed directly (let found how the listener should set the event response)